# How to work with on_member_join and on_member_remove in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just started with discord.py and found out that `on_member_join` and `on_member_remove` don't work for me. Keep in mind that `on_ready` function works perfectly fine.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("""Bot ready""")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(767370104814960640)
    await channel.send(f"{member} has joined the server")

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(766620766237753345)
    await channel.send(f"{member} has left the server")

bot.run("my token")
```

So did I make a mistake with my code or something else went wrong?

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: no there's no error at all

Comment: @xd_ Are you sure `on_member_join` is called? Can you add a print so you can tell if it was called?

Comment: @balderman no it is not called it shows nothing on the console when I kick my alt

Comment: see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_remove. "This requires Intents.members to be enabled."

Answer (score 0):

discord.py 1.5.0 now supports discord API's Privileged Gateway Intents. In order to be able to exploit server data, you need to:

Enable Presence Intent and Server Members Intent in your discord application:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6IE4.png

Use discord.Intents at the beginning of your code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()

#If you use commands.Bot()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

#If you use discord.Client()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Thank you but i think it is `intents = discord.Intents.all()` instead of `intents = Intents.all()`